# while loop keeps repeating itself

Tags: c

I've code:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
```

As I know EOF is equal to -1
I read -1 from keyboard(input stream) and it must stop itself,but loop keeps repeating.
why?

Comment: Try using Ctrl+d or Ctrl+Z

Comment: If you mean you're typing the two characters `-1` then it won't stop (the characters will just be echoed.  EOF is signalled by the end of the file: either `Ctrl-Z` (Windows) or `Ctrl-D` (Unix).

Comment: Note that in a Windows console, the `Ctrl-Z` will only be recognised as `EOF` when it immediately follows a `newline`, otherwise it is treated as value `26`.

Answer (score 2):

`-1` is actually two separate characters `-` and `1` which is not equivalent to EOF. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

As @SouravKanta alludes to: your loop is reading individual characters one at a time, so if you enter -1, it reads the `-` and then the `1`, neither of which indicates EOF.  I believe *Cntl-d* is what you want, at least in *nix (you don't specify the platform).